# Does LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT and LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY still operate in cordova-plugin-file?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Is it sill fully reliable for both android and iOS to use `LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT` and `LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY` within in `cordova-plugin-file`?

```js
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {...})
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, function (fs) {...})
```

I'm confused between the function `window.requestFileSystem` and `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL`. Could you clarify?

Answer (score -1):

> Before you use the File plugin APIs, you can get access to the file
> system using requestFileSystem. When you do this, you can request
> either persistent or temporary storage. Persistent storage will not be
> removed unless permission is granted by the user. Temporary storage
> may be deleted by the operating system if the device runs low on
> memory.

[doc](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/9.x/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html#create-a-temporary-file)

Comment: I already read the docs and they are bad. Thanks for your time but sorry, it didn't answer my question

Comment: What is your question then? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: this is a theoretical question, I'm trying to understand how does it work. Documentations is awful and dealing with files in cordova is painful

Comment: No I understand where you're coming from but "How does it work" is not really suited for SO. Maybe forking the plugin and investigating ? Anyhoo, good luck.